# To appear at a place to do something

Tags: present-tense

Is this sentence grammatically correct and fine to your ears?

> The company's general manager appears at the awards ceremony to receive recognition plaques.

Comment: Is it happening right now? Or do you mean in the future or past?

Comment: Are you at the ceremony, or are you just telling someone about what is happening somewhere else?

Comment: If this is to be reported live or shared (an ongoing event) somewhere, then it is okay. But if this is for a written report to be published or submitted later on, then use 'appeared' or 'attended'.

Answer (score 1):

Your example

> The general manager **appears** at the awards ceremony

describes a person at an event that is currently happening and is grammatically correct and understandable

Other ways to express this in the **present tense** are

> The general manager **is**  at the awards ceremony
>   The general manager **is attending** the awards ceremony
>   The general manager **attends** the awards ceremony

One usually **attends** an event where **attending** implies **appearance**. If there is some special circumstance or reason for being there, it can be called

> **a guest appearance**
>   **a surprise appearance**